# Global MySQL connection or one connection for each request?

Tags: java, mysql, jakarta-ee, servlets

I have several servlets working on a Tomcat server. Now I let them create db connections for each request and close them after use. This may lead to huge overhead for establishing/closing connections. What about using a single connection manager servlet to share a global connection among all servlets (i.e. all servlets use the same connection). Is this a good practice or there may be problems for concurrent operations?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should read about connection pools:

C3PO, BoneCP, DBCP

This are the best and popular connection pools available, i am using BoneCP in my production project.

Answer (score 2):

I think you need to consider using connection pools if possible.

That way you don't need to worry about creating connection/close overhead.

When you want connection you can get it from pool and when you are done with connection, call close() which returns connection to pool.

See this [discussion](http://onjava.com/onjava/2006/04/19/database-connection-pooling-with-tomcat.html) to get understanding on how connection pools work.

Answer (score 1):

> This may lead to huge overhead for establishing/closing connections.

You are right, connection establishment and closing it prove to be costly operations if they are too frequent.

> What about using a single connection manager servlet to share a global connection among all servlets (i.e. all servlets use the same connection)

Though the JDBC specification doesn't prevent the connection from being shared by multiple threads, this is considered a bad practice as it could be driver implementation dependent. So, one connection per database session results in more portable and maintainable code.

The JDBC specification recommends using `DataSource` objects to pool connections to avoid the overhead you mentioned above.

> To obtain a connection, the application may interact with either:
>
> - the DriverManager class working with one or more Driver implementations
>
> OR
>
> - a DataSource implementation
>
> Using a DataSource object is the preferred method because it enhances application
> portability, it makes code maintenance easier, and it makes it possible for an
> application to transparently make use of connection pooling and distributed
> transactions. All J2EE components that establish a connection to a data source use a
> DataSource object to get a connection.